# Scons custom dependency scanner constructor returns NONE object

Tags: python, scons

Following code snippet belongs to a `Sconscript` file.

```
...

def dependency_add(node, env, path):
    print("scanner invoked.")
    return [env.File('src/sanitizer_blacklist.txt')]

dscanner = Scanner(function = dependency_add, skeys=['.c'])

print(dscanner)
...
```

But it turns out that `dscanner` object is `None`. So please suggest why that might be the case. I tried to figure this out from docs but could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Mats said below.

> It's an oddity of the SCons API, not a bug. The default name attribute
> of a scanner object is "NONE", and that's what **str** of the object
> returns. If you supply the name when constructing the object you
> should get something a little more descriptive.

Comment: It's an oddity of the SCons API, not a bug.  The default name attribute of a scanner object is "NONE", and that's what `__str__` of the object returns.  If you supply the name when constructing the object you should get something a little more descriptive.

Comment: Ok. I have one more question. If I want to provide one more scanner for files which already have support for inbuilt scanners. Then, will dependencies recognised by custom scanner be added on top of the one detected by inbuilt scanners?